# Blank page on Zend Framework 2 app deploy

Tags: php, zend-framework2, fedora, webdeploy

I have a Fedora 22 Server all configured, even tested the skeleton app and it works, but if I Copy any app onto it, it just displays a Blank page, no errors, and when I inspect the page it just displays

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body></body>
</html>
```

Note* I do have

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Comment: add `display_errors(1);` and see if you get the errors shown.

Comment: nope, it still a blank page

Comment: can I turn that on from the php.ini instead? maybe it just isn't doing anything from the code

Comment: are you using ini_set? I suggest you do it in your Module.php file. Or as you said, you can turn that on in the php.ini also.

Comment: It works now I had set error_reporting = E_ALL | E_STRICT , it's just error_reporting = E_ALL

Answer (score 0):

I had a wrong configuration for PHP 5.5
I had set

```
error_reporting = E_ALL | E_STRICT
```

and it should be just

```
error_reporting = E_ALL
```